# HP Proliant Array Configuration Utility shows 4TB drive size as zero

Tags: hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I tried adding a pair of 4TB WD RE disks to a HP Proliant ML350 G6 server, but the ACU utility shows them as having a capacity of 0.0 GB.

Is this a known issue? From the documentation for the Smart Array P410 Controller, I believe it should support 4TB drives. I am not planning on using them as a boot drive either, just to add some RAID1 storage to the box.

Comment: What version firmware do you have?

Comment: I am not sure why I got close votes (*"Off topic: Questions should demonstrate reasonable business information technology management practices."*); I am pretty sure 4TB SATA drives should be supported by this controller. The disks themselves are also WD "RE" SATA disks, which are supposed to be their enterprise/datacenter disks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definitely upgrade the firmware of your Smart Array P410i controller and the entire server.

4TB disks *are* compatible with this server and RAID controller provided you're on the right firmware.

Please understand that consumer SATA disks will downshift to 3Gbps speeds on this controller, so that's a factor.

Comment: Thanks, that was it, in the meantime I upgraded the firmware to 6.64
(1 Oct 2015), it was running some old fw. version, probably from the day server was first bought. Just got back from the server room and everything is working fine now (apart from the 3Gbps limit you mentioned, but we were aware this might be an issue).