# HP Proliant ML350 G6 SMH reporting error with Smart Array

Tags: hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, degraded, health

Our HP Proliant ML350 G6 recently turned off by itself for the first time, with the "Health LED" indicating degraded state.

As soon as I pressed the power button, the LED went back to green, so after OS restart, I opened the System Management Homepage. It was showing error state for the Smart Array P410i, but with all the information missing:

[image]

Since I recently [installed a newer fw version on the Smart Array](https://serverfault.com/a/787986/48320), including the new ACU version, I presumed that SMH perhaps doesn't get the correct information from the array, so I started ACU and it indeed doesn't show any problems:

[image]

I installed the newest version of the SMH, but the same error is being shown. ACU seems to believe that everything is ok, and the server is operating without problems otherwise, I don't see any degradation in performance either.

**Is there a way to get more information about what might be wrong?**

Answer (score 1):

This was just a software issue. Maybe SNMP. It doesn't look like you have a problem now.